# c# contravariance and covariance: cannot convert from implementation to interface

Tags: c#, generics, covariance, contravariance

Experts, what is wrong here:

I have these interfaces:

```
public interface IEvent {}

public interface ISingleEventModelChangeInterrogator<in TEvent> where TEvent : IEvent
{
    List<string> GetChangedCandidates(object context, TEvent changedEventArgs);
    bool IsInterestedIn(TEvent changedEventType);
}
```

Then, I have this base class:

```
public abstract class SingleEventModelChangeInterrogator<TEvent> : ISingleEventModelChangeInterrogator<TEvent>
        where TEvent : IEvent
    {
        public abstract List<string> GetChangedCandidates(object context, TEvent changedEventArgs);

        public bool IsInterestedIn(TEvent changedEventType)
        {
            return changedEventType.GetType() == typeof(TEvent);
        }
    }
```

And the following implementations:

```
    public class PriceChangeEvent : IEvent { }

    public class PurchaseOrderAffectedByPriceChangeInterrogator : SingleEventModelChangeInterrogator<PriceChangeEvent >
    {
        public override List<string> GetChangedCandidates(object context, PriceChangeEvent changedEventArgs)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

When I attempt to add an instance of `PurchaseOrderAffectedByPriceChangeInterrogator` to a list of `ISingleEventModelChangeInterrogator<IEvent>`, as shown below:

```
 public class RetailEventCoordinator
    {
        public void Initialize()
        {
            var interrogators = new List<ISingleEventModelChangeInterrogator<IEvent>>();
            interrogators.Add(new PurchaseOrderAffectedByPriceChangeInterrogator());
        }
    }
```

I get the following error:

> cannot convert
> 'model.materialization.service.interrogators.PurchaseOrderAffectedByPriceChangeInterrogator'
> to
> 'model.materialization.service.interrogators.ISingleEventModelChangeInterrogator<dotnet.model.materialization.service.events.IEvent>

What am I missing here?

Comment: It would have worked if it were `out TEvent`, but obviously `TEvent` can't be declared `out`. The assignment you want to do simply doesn't make sense. `PurchaseOrderAffectedByPriceChangeInterrogator` is a consumer of `PriceChangeEvent`.  `ISingleEventModelChangeInterrogator<IEvent>` is a consumer of `IEvent`. A consumer of something more general (`IEvent`) IS A KIND OF consumer of something more specific (`PriceChangeEvent`), not the other way around.

Comment: See [the amazing picture in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19739576/5133585).

Comment: And I am here thinking I have a good handle on generics :)